# Sets not in a sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I have a question concerning some sets which are not in a given sigma-algebra.
More precisely, I have two questions closely related:

Let $\mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \mathbb{R}^d), d \ge 1$, be the set of functions $\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^d$. We denote by $\mathcal{T}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0},\mathbb{R}^d)$ the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the so-called cylindrical sets

$\{ f \in \mathcal{A}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \mathbb{R}^d), f(t_1) \in I_1,...,f(t_n) \in I_n \} $

where $t_1,...,t_n \in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}$ and where $I_1,...,I_n$ are products of intervals: $I_i=\Pi_{k=1}^d (a^k_i,b^k_i]$.

First, I would like to show the following:

1) $\{ f \in \mathcal{A}([0,1], \mathbb{R}), \sup_{t\in [0,1]} f(t) <1 \}$ is *not* in $\mathcal{T} ([0,1],\mathbb{R})$.

Then if we define similarly (for continuous functions),

$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0},\mathbb{R}^d)$ is the sigma-algebra on $\mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \mathbb{R}^d) $ generated by the sets

$\{ f \in \mathcal{C}(\mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}, \mathbb{R}^d), f(t_1) \in I_1,...,f(t_n) \in I_n \} $

then

2) $\{ f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R}), \sup_{t\in [0,1]} f(t) <1 \}$ *is* in $\mathcal{B}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$

Now a few comments:
First these exercises come from the following blog:

[Blog from Fabrice Baudoin](https://fabricebaudoin.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/lecture-2-measure-theory-in-function-spaces/)

Then, I found a very similar topic on another stack exchange forum:

[How do I show this set is not in this σ
-algebra?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/172070/how-do-i-show-this-set-is-not-in-this-sigma-algebra)

which is about proving the opposite of my point 2). i.e that

$\{ f \in \mathcal{C}([0,1], \mathbb{R}), \sup_{t\in [0,1]} f(t) <1 \}$ is *not* in $\mathcal{B}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$.

Someone answered the question and gave a proof, but I think there is a mistake in the proof. It starts like this:

"Each set in $\mathcal{B}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$ is of the following form:

$\{ f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d) : f(t_i)\in M_i\ i\in \mathbb{N} \}$

where $(t_i)_{i\in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence in $[0,1]$, and $M_i$ is a sequence of Borel sets."

But in fact the set $\{ f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d) : f(0)\in [0,1] \}\cup \{ f\in C([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d) : f(1)\in [3,4] \} $ is not of the form above despite being in the sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}([0,1],\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I would have put a comment to the post, but I don't have enough reputation.

It is also possible that I missed a little difference between the two settings, in which case I apologize. If anyone has an idea to show point 1) and 2), I would be glad to read it.